# Answer the questions in one word with help of clues and images given

Tags: microbiology, homework

Name the things associated with Antonie Van Leeuwenhoek - (6 pictures are given for help and four of them are associated with these clues)

a)Leeuwenhoek was the first to describe these and hence called the "Father of Microbiology"

b)He found many of these (rotifers) in the rainwater collected in ditches and canals

c)Leeuwenhoek was the first to describe plant vessels in this cross section of an ash tree

d)Leeuwenhoek used this to observe microorganisms.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic unless you show some effort to solve them yourself.

Comment: How far did you come? What did you find out?

Comment: I found the following - A) Microorganism B) Rotifera C)Fraxinus D) Microscope

Comment: These answers look fine for me.

Comment: right click the image, "search google for this image"

Comment: Wanted to post this as an answer but can't since your question is on hold. So I'll post the links to the answers. 1) http://www.infection-research.de/perspectives/view/detail/23/shape_matters_why_bacteria_care_how_they_look/ 2) image of a rotifer http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/Bdelloid_Rotifer.jpg 3) ash tree cross-section http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Popular_Science_Monthly/Volume_45/July_1894/Sunshine_Through_the_Woods 4) http://www.history-of-the-microscope.org/anton-van-leeuwenhoek-microscope-history.php  ... You go through these pages and you will get all your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have apparently tried to answer the question here is my interpretation. I list the six pictures (numbered from top to bottom) and link four of them to an answer.

1 - yeast cells?

2 -  ash tree section (c)

3 - rotifer (b)

4 - muscle fibre??

5 - bacteria? (a)

6 - Leeuwenhoek's microscope (d)

According to the WP page on [van Leeuwenhoek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonie_van_Leeuwenhoek) he did describe the banded pattern in muscle, but there is no mention of yeast (although he would have had no trouble seeing these cells if he could see bacteria).

It's a very odd question.